# Alias from haversine distance calculation used in HAVING clause in Mysql not having any effect

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code (source: Ollie at plumisland):

```
$query = "SELECT $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
,111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS($latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat))
             * COS(RADIANS($longpoint) - RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lng))
            + SIN(RADIANS($latpoint))
             * SIN(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat)))) AS distance_in_km
FROM $table     
LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
ON UPPER($table.postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode
WHERE
$where_no_and
AND 
(hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR hide='')
HAVING distance_in_km <= 10
ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage
";
```

Everyhing works but the 'HAVING distance_in_km <= 10' is not having any effect. It does not reduce the list of results to those within 10 km.

I have done a PHP calculation of distance to show the actual distance for each row of result as a backup check.

Sample of results shown below:

```
calc-dist is 57.8558548681, Entfernung ist 57.76155432
Lat=51.609922000000000, Lng=0.645703000000000   
1 Bedroom Flat For Sale £142
Hullbridge Hullbridge SS5 Essex England
Available with No Onward Chain is this purpose built Ground floor 
One Bedroom Apartment located in an attractive block within easy 
access of all village amenities and the River Crouch
More info/photos/map To discuss email agent (Prop: 3976)
Agent: Hullbridge Village and Park Homes

calc-dist is 557.289608887, Entfernung ist 556.381270123
Lat=56.094297000000000, Lng=-3.525096000000000  
2 Bedroom Flat For Sale £49,950
Sunnybraes Terrace Saline Steelend KY12 Fife Scotland
Spacious Upper Flat EPC - E
More info/photos/map To discuss email agent (Prop: 1995)
Agent: Able Agents

calc-dist is 566.191606711, Entfernung ist 565.268758382
Lat=56.115000000000000, Lng=-3.781000000000000  
1 Bedroom Flat For Sale £55,000
Mar Street Alloa Alloa FK10 Falkirk Scotland
Refurbished Flat EPC : D
More info/photos/map To discuss email agent (Prop: 4091)
Agent: Able Agents

calc-dist is 24.1715086823Entfernung ist 24.1321110012
Lat=51.479398000000000, Lng-0.179717000000000   
0 Bedroom Studio For Sale £59,995
Frobisher Road Erith DA8
ableestates.com/ LOW PRICE FOR QUICK SALE * IDEAL INVESTMENT OPPOTUNITY 
More info/photos/map To discuss email agent (Prop: 2133)
Agent: Able Estates"
```

None of these 4 results should be present since their distances are greater that the 10km stipulated in the 'HAVING distance_in_km <= 10' clause.

calc-dist and Entfernung (German for distance) were distances calculated in PHP using two different versions of the haversine formula.

The Lat and Lng values are also shown

Admittedly these PHP distance calculations were done after the mysql results had been evaluated using:
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {

Comment: Where is your `FROM`?

Comment: Sorry Uueerdo, the FROM is present but somehow got deleted when I was indenting by 4 spaces. Here is that part of the code:                      FROM $table 
LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
ON UPPER($table.postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode

Comment: You should be able to edit that back into your question.

Comment: Show a subset of some actual results of your query, and then show the same set but with ones you think shouldn't be in it removed.

Comment: calc-dist is 57.8558548681Entfernung ist 57.76155432
1 Bedroom Flat 51.609922000000000 0.645703000000000 For Sale £142

calc-dist is 557.289608887Entfernung ist 556.381270123 
2 Bedroom Flat 56.094297000000000 -3.525096000000000 For Sale £49,950
Sunnybraes Terrace Saline Steelend KY12 Fife Scotland
Spacious Upper Flat EPC - E

Comment: Again, that would be better added to the question, and formatted appropriately; and it is hard to tell, but does not look like actual query results.

Comment: Thanks Ueerdo. I have added a sample of the results to the question as you suggested

Comment: Why didn't you include the `distance_in_km` values` that the query returned?

Comment: @Uueerdo, re your question "Why didn't you include the distance_in_km values` that the query returned?", that is the crux of the problem. How do I get this value? I have tried echoing it as well as trying to get it via a mysql_search_array($result). No success

Answer (score 0):

You don't have from  your_table  .. a seems you are not using  aggregation function  so you don't have group by and for this you don't should  use having but where  (or and)

```
    "SELECT $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
    ,111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS($latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat))
                 * COS(RADIANS($longpoint) - RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lng))
                + SIN(RADIANS($latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat)))) AS distance_in_km
    LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
    FROM $table
    ON UPPER($table.postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode
    WHERE
    $where_no_and
    AND 
    (hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR hide='')
    AND distance_in_km <= 10
    ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage"
```

You have also a lot of var inside the query  and not all properly quoted ... if you are sure for a proper sanitize ao all thi  vars against sql injection you  could use a query using concatenation

```
    "SELECT " . $table .".*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
    ,111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(". $latpoint ."))
                 * COS(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat))
                 * COS(RADIANS(". $longpoint .") - RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lng))
                + SIN(RADIANS(" . $latpoint " ))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat)))) AS distance_in_km
    LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
    FROM " . $table . 
    "  ON UPPER(" . $table. " .postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode
    WHERE " .
    $where_no_and . 
    "  AND 
    (hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR hide='')
    AND (outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
    ,111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(". $latpoint ."))
                 * COS(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat))
                 * COS(RADIANS(". $longpoint .") - RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lng))
                + SIN(RADIANS(" . $latpoint " ))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat)))))  <= 10
    ORDER BY rent " . $reihenach . "  LIMIT  " .  $offset . ", " . $rowsPerPage
```

Comment: Can't use alias, distance_in_km, in WHERE clause.

Comment: @ScaisEdge, I did repeat the code in a where clause but it did not work. However, I did not put the vars in quotes nor did I use concatenation as you suggested. Can I put vars in quotes without the concatenation?

Comment: i don't .know . depend ..for the number quote are  not required .. but for string could be .. and for table in vars is not easy without concatenation ..

Comment: My question answered. I tried putting vars in quotes without concatenation and got this error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/properf/public_html/4Tsalepf.php on line 584

Comment: @ScaisEdge, thanks. I will try your concatenated code and see how that works.

Comment: @ScaisEdge, Just putting vars in concatenated quotes did not solve the problem (including repeating the code in a where clause). Copying your whole concatenated code threw the succeeding code out as there must have been a stop or a quote missing somewhere. I will try and investigate.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING is used to filter GROUP BY result. There is no GROUP BY so HAVING is simply ignored. To filter results by derived column values you have to repeat expression in WHERE or encapsulate query in VIEW and select form it.

Comment: MySQL will still process HAVING conditions, even without grouped results.

Comment: UPD: MySQL processes HAVING without GROUP BY until sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is set.

Comment: sql_mode by default is empty string (no additional rules), up to 5.6. In 5.7, default sql_mode is [TRADITIONAL,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html). So old code written relying on dangerous MySQL features is incompatible with 5.7+ versions. Of course, it is possible to overwrite sql_mode, but it is strongly recommended to stick with strict mode acquired by TRADITIONAL,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to make sql code much more predictable and portable to other RDBMS' like SQL Server.

Comment: 5.7.5+ specifically according to the link you provided. Ironically, it looks like they also re-allowed using aliases in HAVING (with that option enabled) in that and later releases, making the queries once again less portable (at least to MS SQL).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116023/discussion-between-aleksey-ratnikov-and-uueerdo).